# Why do [1 0 0 1] and [-1 0 0 -1] represent the same physical state?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

Below screen shot is from qiskit textbook
[image]

Because the differences between each of the amplitudes is the same. You could say these two vectors are different mathematically, but the same physically.

why the difference between each of amplitudes is considered to decide this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22078/55

Comment: yes, please mark duplicate...thanks @glS